# Cardinal Inequality without using Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $k$ be an infinite cardinal (i.e. not in bijection with any natural number), show that

$\mathbb{N} \leq 2^{2^k}$

This is very easy with choice, without it I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

- If $k$ is infinite, then $k$ contains subsets of every finite size.
- Of course, there will be *many* subsets of $k$ of each finite size.
- Do you see how to identify a given natural number $n$ with a certain family of subsets of $k$?

Comment: By induction we know that $k$ contains a subset of cardinality $n$ for any natural number $n$. So we can define a function $f:\mathbb{N}−>P(P(k))$ which maps n to the set of subsets of cardinality n. This function is clearly injective. Is this correct?

Comment: @Tim Yup, that's it. By the way, if you play around with this for a while, you'll see that it's very hard to get an injection $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow P(k)$ - it turns out that there need not be one! (Although actually proving possible nonexistence is of course extremely hard, and requires **forcing**.)